# Creating an oval shape with a size relative to the display size

Tags: android

I need a custom shape which should look like this:

[image]

The style of the shape is stroke so the orange part of that example is the border of the circle. The white part here is not part of the shape! it is the color of the layout under the shape. I hope you understand what i mean. The shape should not draw the white circle in the middle the shape should draw the orange stuff.

Even more: I need the width and the height of the white circle to be relative to the screen size. If the screen width is smaller than the height i need the white circle's radius to be width / 2 and if the height is smaller than the width i need the circle's radius to be height / 2.

There is really nothing i could find to achiev this. I thought that would be an easy task because its a simple drawing but android seems to make it hard to achiev since the shape's always setting fix dp for width and height like 120dp in the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

   <solid 
       android:color="#666666"/>

   <size 
       android:width="120dp"
       android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```

I need this drawable as an overlay for an imageview.

Comment: If you need to perform this all at the drawable level, then you will need a custom `Drawable` implementing this. If you can do this at the layout level, then you can use a `LinearLayout` with the desired background with dummy views at the top and bottom with a weight of 1/4 each, containing the `ImageView` with a PNG image resource to draw the actual transparent circle.

Answer (score 0):

Did you thought about setting the width and height of your shape during runtime?

You can find out the width and height of the screen like this:

```
int width = yourView.getWidth(); int height = yourView.getHeight();
```

or just

```
int width = getWidth(); int height = getHeight();
```

or

```
Context c = context;
DisplayMetrics metrics = c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
```

In the last example you need to get the context variable from somewhere.

Then you divide it by 2 and set the shape.

Comment: I tried that. i could not find any solution where i can dynamically set the radius of the shape programmatically. i cant change the size of the layout because it must be macht_parent, always because i want everything of the screen except the circle in the middle to be one color.

Comment: How about creating a simple orange image with paint/gimp/photoshop that has a transparent hole in the middle. Then you load it during runtime and resize it to the screen size of your view and draw it. That way the hole should always have the same size relative to the screensize but might be an elipse if the width is not the same as the height

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by making use of ShapeDrawable in white circle drawable.

Take one relative layout with full orange background and add imageview with white circle drawable.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: no this actually wouldnt work. the white circle must ist the background of the underlayout layout so it is transparent.